# Reactive Cocoa `then` operator

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4

I couldn't find much documentation about RAC `then` operator. What is the purpose it serves. When should I use. it? Can someone explain in below context?

```
[[[[self requestAccessToTwitterSignal]
  then:^RACSignal *{
    @strongify(self)
    return self.searchText.rac_textSignal;
  }]
  filter:^BOOL(NSString *text) {
    @strongify(self)
    return [self isValidSearchText:text];
  }]
  subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"%@", x);
  } error:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
  }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code documentation provide a sound explanation.

```
/// Ignores all `next`s from the receiver, waits for the receiver to complete,
/// then subscribes to a new signal.
///
/// block - A block which will create or obtain a new signal to subscribe to,
///         executed only after the receiver completes. This block must not be
///         nil, and it must not return a nil signal.
///
/// Returns a signal which will pass through the events of the signal created in
/// `block`. If the receiver errors out, the returned signal will error as well.
```

So in your context. it waits until requestAccessToTwitterSignal complete. Ignores any event after that. And `then` subscribes to the new signal. Which is `self.searchText.rac_textSignal`. The `filter` applies to the new signal.

Answer (score 2):

It essentially just makes the signal you apply it to work as a delay, it won't send `next` events until the original signal completes, at which point it'll switch to the signal you supplied with `then:`.

`requestAccessToTwitterSignal` will do something stateful and set a twitter token of some kind, so we use `then:` to wait until it's done and return a new signal that we want to get `next` events from.